# How to split string in JavaScript with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following html. I want to split it by `<span>` tag.

```
let storyHtml = "<span>People</span> born in different ages are different from each other in various aspects. The world is changing at <span>a</span> rapid pace and thus the difference between <span>people</span> born in different times is inevitable.";

let allSplitPart = storyHtml.split(/<span>.*?<\/span>/gim); 
let allMatchPart = storyHtml.match(/<span>.*?<\/span>/gim);

// Output 1: ["", " born in different ages are different from each other in various aspects. The world is changing at ", " rapid pace and thus the difference between ", " born in different times is inevitable."] 

//Output 2: ["<span>People</span>", "<span>a</span>", "<span>people</span>"]
```

**What output I want:**

```
["<span>People</span>", " born in different ages are different from each other in various aspects. The world is changing at ","<span>a</span>"," rapid pace and thus the difference between ","<span>people</span>", " born in different times is inevitable."]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `<span>.*?<\/span>` of the regex inside `()` for it to be included.

```js
let storyHtml = "<span>People</span> born in different ages are different from each other in various aspects. The world is changing at <span>a</span> rapid pace and thus the difference between <span>people</span> born in different times is inevitable.";

console.log(storyHtml.split(/(<span>.*?<\/span>)/i).filter(Boolean));
```

The `filter(Boolean)` removes any empty strings that occur if the string starts or ends with a span, or if two spans dont have any text between them.

Comment: `.filter(Boolean)` is another nice way to filter out falsy values.

Comment: `m` and `g` are redundant here.